# Fastest way to replace values in a numpy array with a list

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I want to read a list into a numpy array. This list is being replaced in every iteration of a loop and further operations are done on the array. These operations include element-wise subtraction from another numpy array for a distance measure, and checking a threshold condition in this distance using the numpy.all() function. Currently I am using `np.array( list )` each time to convert the list to an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
a = [1.33,2.555,3.444,5.666,4.555,6.777,8.888]
%timeit b = np.array(a)

100000 loops, best of 3: 4.83 us per loop
```

Is it possible to do anything better than this, if I know the size of the list and it is invariable? Even small improvements are welcome, as I run this a very large number of times.

I've tried `%timeit(np.take(a,range(len(a)),out=b))` which takes much longer: `100000 loops, best of 3: 16.8 us per loop`

Comment: In my opinion there is no faster way of converting a list to a `numpy.array`. I would rather try to vectorize your `for` loop. Can you be more specific what you do with the `numpy.array` ?

Comment: Edited my question with the operations required.

Comment: Where does the list come from?  Can you use numpy earlier in your calculations to avoid creating a list?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser No, I can't use numpy earlier in my calculation, this comes from a simulation engine, which I have little or no control over.

Comment: If the lists aren't that big, it might be faster to do everything with list operations.  There is some overhead in creating an array.

Comment: @hpaulj That's actually a valuable suggestion. I replaced all the processes I had with list comprehensions and python functions, and did gain a considerable speedup, as my lists are between 5-10 elements big, albeit on a small cost of code readability, but that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you "know the size of the list and it is invariable", you can set up an array first:

```
b = np.zeros((7,))
```

This then works faster:

```
%timeit b[:] = a
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 µs per loop
```

vs

```
%timeit b = np.array(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, this is marginally better. If there is nothing better than this, I'll accept it as an answer,

Comment: I ended up considerably speeding up by using hpaulj's suggestion of not using numpy arrays at all. However this is still the correct and best answer to the above question, thanks!